# Green Lantern comic with Hal or Guy offering another character a pack of alien beer

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, green-lantern

I have a recollection of a couple of panels from a Green Lantern comic depicting a Lantern offering another character an alien beer/brew out of a crate. I have no other memory of the plot. Judging by what I remember of the art, this would likely have been published after 2000, possibly during the Geoff Johns years.

The two characters may have been on Mogo, and the second one *might* have been a relative of the Green Lantern, but that may be influenced by my recent re-reading of the Controllers arc (starting from *Hal Jordan and the Green Lantern Corps* #33, 2017).

The Green Lantern, who I'm fairly sure was human, praised a special kind of alien beer/brew and suggested they had one; I remember him being Hal Jordan, but Guy Gardner is also very likely. I strongly doubt it would have been John Stewart or Kyle Rayner, and I don't think Jessica Cruz and Simon Baz even existed at that point.

Re-reading multiples issues and Googling stuff like `dc green lantern alien brew site:dc.fandom.com` made me eliminate:

- anything in *Green Lantern* #1-67 (2005-2011)
- anything in *Green Lantern: Emerald Warriors* #1-13 (2010-2011)
- anything in *Blackest Night* #0-8 (2009-2010)
- anything in *Brightest Day* #1-24 (2010-2011)
- anything in *Green Lantern Corps* #35-63 (2009-2011), not even the Kyle/Guy beer in issue #47 (2010)

  [image: Kyle and Guy share a beer]
- Guy snatching a crate of Vuldarian microbrew in *Hal Jordan and the Green Lantern Corps* #34 (2017)

  [image: Guy popping a Vuldarian microbrew open]

Comment: Probably not *Green Lantern Corps 8* which has a bar brawl. https://retcon-punch.com/2012/04/23/green-lantern-corps-8/amp/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no, indeed, but good catch

Comment: Yes, the above lead me to some serious Green Lantern binge-re-reading; yes, there are more important things I should tend to; no, I absolutely don't regret it. Those DC Comics years were awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Green Lantern* #34 (2014).

I had Hal, Mogo, and the relative part right (the other one is Hal's brother, Jim). What I had wrong is that this is post-Geoff Johns, and Simon Baz already existed; it's actually him who brought Hal's family on Mogo to visit him, as Hal could not go back to Earth, which was in Red Lantern territory.

The beer is Khundish ale.

[image: Hal and Jim Jordan sitting on a cliff, sharing a couple of Khundish ales]